# Does the distance between read and write locations have an effect on cache performance?

Tags: c, performance

I have a buffer of size `n` that is full, and a successor buffer of size `n` that is empty. I want to insert a value within the first buffer at position `i`, but I would need to move a range of memory forward in order to do that, since the buffer is full (ie. sequential insert). I have two options here:

Prefer write close to read (adjacent):

1. Push the last value of the first buffer into the second.
2. Move between `i` and `n - 1` in the first buffer one forward.
3. Insert at `i`.

Prefer fewer steps:

1. Copy the range `i` to `n - 1` from the first into the second buffer.
2. Insert at `i`.

Most of what I can find only talks about locality in a *read* context, and I am wondering whether the distance between the read and the write memory should be considered.

Comment: I assume you've already considered the option of using a different data structure that allows insertion without moving large chunks of memory?

Comment: @NateEldredge this is a component deep within a data structure at the lowest level where `n` is small and constant.

Comment: Memory is typically paged, e.g., https://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/memory-paging (google "paged memory", or similar search, for lots more hits). So memory's swapped in/out as pages are needed. And if your read/write buffers are larger than a single page (which I'm inferring they likely are),  then I wouldn't think it'll matter what the "distance" between them is. All that matters with respect to swapping is that they're different pages, regardless of "distance".

Comment: The size of the buffer will never exceed 1kb.

Comment: @rtheunissen _"buffer will never exceed 1kb"_ Then, yeah, keep them "together". malloc() one larger 2K buffer, and just declare two pointers **unsigned char *inbuff=twoKbuff, *outbuff=twoKbuff+1000;** or something along those lines. But if you're experiencing disk thrashing or some other i/o bottlenecks, I'd doubt this is your problem. It's nevertheless easy to fix, as illustrated, and can't hurt to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the distance between read and write locations have an effect on cache performance?

Yes. Normally (not including rare situations where CPU can write an entire cache line with new data) the CPU has to fetch the most recent version of a cache line into its cache before doing the write. If the cache line is already in the cache (e.g. due to a previous read of some other data that happened to be in the same cache line) then CPU won't need to fetch the cache line before doing the write.

Note that there's also various other quirks (cache aliasing, TLB misses, etc); and all of it depends on the specific situation and which CPU (e.g. if all of the process' data fits in the CPU's cache, there's no shared memory in involved, and there's no task switches or other processes using the CPU; then you can assume everything will always be in the cache anyway).

> I want to insert a value within the first buffer at position `i`, but I would need to move a range of memory forward in order to do that, since the buffer is full (ie. sequential insert).

Without more information (how often this happens, how much data is involved, etc) I can't really make any suggestions. However (at first glance, without much information), the entire idea seems bad. More specifically, it sounds like you're adding a bunch of hassle to make two smaller arrays behave exactly the same as one larger array would have (and then worrying about the cost of insertion because arrays aren't good for insertion in general).

Answer (score 1):

> this is a component deep within a data structure at the lowest level where n is **small** and constant

by small I assume you mean smaller than L1 cpu cache of being somewhere less than 1MB or L2 cache up to 10-20 MB, depending on your CPU then no,

> I am wondering whether the distance between the read and the write memory should be considered.

sometimes; if all the data can fit into the CPU L1, L2, L3 cache that the process is running on then what you think *random access* means applies it would all be the same latency.  You can get nitty gritty and delve into the differences between L1, L2, L3 cache but for sake of brevity (and i simply take it for granted) anywhere within a memory *boundary* it's all the same latency to access.  So in your case where N is small and if it all fits into cpu cache (the first of many boundaries) then it would be the manner and efficiency in which you chose to move/change values and the number of times you end up doing that which affects performance (time to complete).

Now if *N* were big, for example in a 2 or more socket system (over intel QPI or UPI) and that data resided on DDR RAM that is located across the QPI or UPI path to memory dimms off the memory controller of the other CPU, then definitely yes big performance hit (relatively speaking) because now a *boundary* has been crossed, and that would be what could NOT fit into cache of the CPU that the process was running on (which was initally fetched from DIMMS LOCAL to that cpu memory controller) now incurs the overhead talking to the other CPU over the QPI or UPI path (while still very fast compared to previous architecures) and that other CPU then fetches the data from it's set of memory DIMMS and sends it back over QPI or UPI to the cpu your process is running on.

So when you exceed L1 cache limit into L2 there is a performance hit, likewise into L3 cache, all within one CPU.  when a process has to repeatedly fetch from it's local set of dimms more data that it could not fit into cache then performance hit.  And when that data is not on dimms local to that cpu = slower.  And when that data is not on the same motherboard and goes across some kind of high speed fiber RDMA = slower.  When it's across ethernet even slower... and so on.